# Assign static IP to GCP SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to assign a static IP to a SQL replica database instance, so that I can delete and recreate it with the same IP address. I dont see any way to do this. Can this be done for SQL, or only for Google Compute Engine instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today it’s not possible to assign a static IP to a Cloud SQL instance as it is for GCE. When you create an instance, a random IP is assigned and when you delete the instance that IP is released. Also, the deleted instance name can’t be reused for up to a week according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/delete-instance)

Comment: The linked documentation has since been updated to note that the instance name can now be reused immediately: "The deleted instance name can be reused immediately to create a new instance." Unfortunately it seems the IP is still lost when deleting an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, But you can assign static IP to a Compute Engine Instance and setup your SQL replica over that machine. And when you've given proper rights in the SQL Roles you'd be able to drop/create the database over the same machine with same IP.